# How do I remove an app folder is OSX when all else fails?

Tags: macos, hfs

I have a folder/package in the Applications called CrashPlan.app. The uninstall failed and I am left with a folder that has a Contents folder, but aside from that, is completely empty.

The folder info:

```
drwxrwxr-x@ 3 root 102 13 Jul 20:36 CrashPlan.app
```

I have tried the following:

```
sudo rm -rf CrashPlah.app chown chflags nouchg
```

I tried the same things in Safe Mode and Recovery Mode. I tried disabling System Integrity Protection. Whenever I try to remove the folder I get: rm: CrashPlan.app/Contents: Operation not permitted rm: CrashPlan.app: Operation not permitted

Does anyone have any advise? I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: Crash plan has an uninstaller on the dmg you download use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I jumped a gun posting here and got the answer elsewhere.  Here is the solution:
Because uninstall has already failed, the problem may be that the "system immutable flag" is set for /Applications/CrashPlan.app or its contents. In Terminal, try

```
ls -ldO /Applications/CrashPlan.app
```

and

```
ls -ldO /Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents
```

The ls command may show something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x@  3 root  102  schg   13 Jul 14 20:36 CrashPlan.app
```

If you see the schg flag, run these commands:

```
sudo chflags -R noschg /Applications/CrashPlan.app
sudo rm -fR /Applications/CrashPlan.app
```